# Complex command in exec.Command()

Tags: bash, docker, go

I want to exec this command:

```
docker exec -it demoContainer bash -c "pip freeze" > "requirements.txt"
```

But don't find any example of this kind of complex commands with pipes, and output writes.

I tryed this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec -it demoContainer bash -c \"pip freeze\" > \"requirements.txt\"")
_, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

And:

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", "demoContainer", "bash", "-c", "pip freeze", ">", "scheduleDeploy/requirements.txt")
_, err = cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

But always crash with the following output:

```
Error: Exit status 1
```

**Edit**

Updates with answers ideas:

```
err = exec.Command("sh", "-c","'docker exec -it demoContainer bash -c 'pip freeze' > 'requirements.txt''").Run()
```

Output:

```
Exit error status 2
```

Comment: @tripleee \" are necesary in order to say where the command starts for -c

Comment: The argument to `-c` should be a single string, but in your second attempt, there should be no additional quotes.

Comment: Can you run this command in your normal host development environment, possibly in a Python virtual environment?  It seems odd to use a debug tool like `docker exec` to do this, and I wouldn't usually script `docker exec` commands at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm already testing it on my computer and it works properly and create the requieremets with the output pip freeze of the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the shell for redirection, you can just let Go do it:

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "os/exec"
)

func main() {
   f, e := os.Create("requirements.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   c := exec.Command(
      "docker", "exec", "-it", "demoContainer", "bash", "-c", "pip freeze",
   )
   c.Stdout = f
   c.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `>` redirection is a "shell" thing, not an "exec" thing. You will need to do one of "run bash, with the command you want executed" or "open a file, set the resulting os.File as the Stdout of the exec.Command, before starting it".

Either would probably solve the issue you are facing.

To use the "bash -c" version, something like:

```
    exec.Command("bash", "-c", `docker exec -it demoContainer bash -c "pip freeze" > requirements.txt`)
```

Comment: @Vatine Can you share an example? I'm just starting in golang

Comment: I understant that with the first option you mean: 

err = exec.Command("bash", "docker exec -it demoContainer bash -c 'pip freeze' > 'sheduleDeploy/requirements.txt'").Run()

But it crash with: 
exit status 127

Comment: Also tried:  

err = exec.Command("sh", "-c","'docker exec -it demoContainer bash -c 'pip freeze' > 'requirements.txt''").Run()

With error exit status 2

Comment: @Loren You have asked sh to execute a command named `'docker`. The quotes you need on a command line are there to stop the shell from splitting arguments on spaces, the arguments in `exec.Command` are simply elements in the `[]string` you pass in. In your example, the only single quotes that may be necessary are the ones around `pip freeze`.